# psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist (with -h localhost option)

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I have Postgres installed in my local machine.

When I execute

```
psql -U postgres -d buzzsumo
```

it correctly asks for my password to the user postgres.

However, when I run

```
psql -U postgres -d buzzsumo -h localhost
```

it gives me this error message:

> psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Why is this the case, when in the first example I am connecting to my local server, which is equivalent to passing in localhost?

Comment: Have you find anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say but I'm guessing you're running postgres on either on MacOS or Linux.

The first form (with no -h) connects via a "unix socket".  The second form, with "-h localhost" connects via TCP/IP to localhost (IP address 127.0.0.1).

Postgres treats these two types of connections differently - or at least, it can do so.  If you check the "pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf" file to see what authentication mechanisms are configured for the two types of connections.

Comment: But why is role not found is coming? role is there right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example connects via Unix socket, the second one via TCP/IP local loop (localhost).

For the first example, you need the connection type `local` in [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), for the second lines starting with `host` are relevant. You probably have defined different [authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html) for these classes of connections.

Comment: But why is role not found is coming? role is there right ?