# rails with postgresl database "role postgres does not exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I installed postgres in my rails application, but I cannot create any roles.
For `su - postgres` and `psql -d template1 -U postgres` I get `psql:FATAL role "postgres" does exist`
I also ran `createuser -s -U $USER`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? Which OS are you using?

Comment: which is your `database.yml`?

Comment: `default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: pigo_development`

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14 and I installed postgresql with sudo apt-get install postgresql

Comment: have you already run `service postgresql initdb`?

Comment: I ran it, but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I tried with `sudo -i -u postgres` `createuser --interactive`. it prompts the question shall the new role be a superuser? I press y and then I get `psql: FATAL:  role "bogdan" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of already answered questions:

- [psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist (with -h localhost option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845348/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist-with-h-localhost-option)
- [psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)
- [psql: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist)

Depending on how you installed PostgeSQL, you may not have the role `postgres`. For instance, on my machine, when I install PostgreSQL via Homebrew, the install creates the default user as the current logged in user, not `postgres`.

Therefore, to login I must use

```
psql -U <myuser> -h localhost
```

and not

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

You may get the error

```
psql: FATAL:  database "<user>" does not exist
```

In that case, follow the instructions in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist) to create the user database.

Comment: thanks for the info, I tried with `sudo -i -u postgres` `createuser --interactive`. it prompts the question shall the new role be a superuser? I press y and then I get `psql: FATAL:  role "bogdan" does not exist`.

Comment: Where does `sudo -i -u postgres` come from? I never mentioned it. Please read my answer and the associated answers.